# Stuck using fonts on tkinter for python 3.x.

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Basically, I can't set the "underline" and "overstrike" options. My code works perfectly until I try to add those parameters in as a label font:

> *Large_Font = ("Verdana", 10, "bold", "italic", **"underline and overstrike"**)*
>
> ...
>
> *Lbl = tk.Label(frame_1, text = "Data", **font = Large_Font**)*

No matter if I type "0 or 1" or "True or False". Anyone can help me out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new [`Font`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_fonts.htm) instance and change its `underline` and `overstrike` attributes to `True`.

```
from tkinter import font

large_font = font.Font(family="Verdana", size=10, weight="bold", slant="italic", underline=True, overstrike=True)
```

or

```
large_font = font.Font(family="Verdana", size=10)
large_font.configure(weight="bold")
large_font.configure(slant="italic")
large_font.configure(underline=True)
large_font.configure(overstrike=True)
```